# Random sampling from dictionary list values based on an integar value from another dictionary, with matching keys

Tags: python, dictionary, random

I have two dictionaries, one has items with lists to random sample from:

```
candidates_to_sample_from = {'PCP3': ['member3', 'member12', 'member17'],
 'PCP4': ['member14', 'member15', 'member16']}
```

The other has matching keys and the number of samples to draw from and ultimately remove from the pool of members:

```
sample_counts = Counter({'PCP3': 2, 'PCP4': 1})
```

I tried doing it two ways without the results I expected.  One way is this:

```
for prov, lst in candidates_to_sample_from.items():
    for i, j in sample_counts.items():
        candidates_out = random.sample(lst, j)

print(candidates_out)
['member16']
```

This produces only the 1 chosen person from the second item in `candidate_to_sample_from` but not the two who should be chose from the first item.

Then I also tried creating an empty list and appending to it:

```
candidates_out = []

for prov, lst in candidates_to_sample_from_dict.items():
    for i, j in sample_counts.items():
        candidates_out.append(random.sample(lst, j))

print(candidates_out)
[['member3', 'member12'], ['members17'], ['member16', 'member14'], ['member16']]
```

I'm trying to just get a simple list like:

```
candidates_out = ['member3', 'member17', 'member15']
```

This has two from item one of `candidates_to_sample_from` and one from the second.  This is a smaller model, it should work the same no matter what the size and scope of the dictionaries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
candidates_out = []
for k, v in sample_counts.items():
    candidates_out += random.sample(candidates_to_sample_from[k], v)
```